# How to use a element function in template polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I want to use a function defined in the element. Like this:

```
<template>
<span onclick="this.parentElement.test();"></span>
</template>

<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'test-ele',
  test: function() {
    console.log('This is a test message.')
  }
})
</script>
```

Is there a similar approach?

```
<template>
<span onclick="{{{test}}}"></span>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To add event listeners to local DOM children, use **on-*event*** annotations in your template. This often eliminates the need to give an element an id solely for the purpose of binding an event listener.

Source: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#annotated-listeners

```
<dom-module id="test-ele">
  <template>
    <span on-click="test">Click Here</span>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'test-ele',
      test: function() {
        console.log('This is a test message.');
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is `no, you can't`. `<span onclick="{{{test}}}"></span>` will try to initiate the function `{{{test}}}`, instead of reading it as a template variable.

Further more, your first example is wrong.

```
<template>
<span onclick="this.parentElement.test();"></span>
</template>
```

will try to load `this.parentElement.test();` as the function. Simply use

```
<template>
<span onclick="test"></span>
</template>
```

Polymer knows it should call a function in the parent element.